# Orientation change while editing a comment

Tags: bug, android-app

If the device fits an orientation change while I am editing a comment, the Post button and down arrow no longer respond to taps.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: VS425PP

  - OS Version: 5.1.1 (161331805d4f5)